# Unable to use T-Mobile/HTC Comet for Android development

Tags: android, usb, comet

I want to run my application on HTC Comet. I have Android 2.2 installed and I use Eclipse. Based on what is given in http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html - I found that I have " USB Driver for Windows, Revision 3" installed. So then I go to Perform a fresh installation for Windows XP.
Even if point to the USB Driver package that has been installed, I get the message  that explains that the driver that I am pointing to is not a match for the device. 
Two USB drivers come with HTC Comet - one for ActiveSync and the other is ADB Driver. 
Please let em know if I ma missing something here - in the meantime I will install the ADB driver. Thank you

Comment: The ADB driver should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mibollma - using ADB Driver worked!

BTW, one other thing I realized was that for the "Device Choser" to appear as stated in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html, I had to make sure that under "Debug configurations" menu option, then select the Target tab and set "Deployment Target Selection Mode" to Automatic.